# Display only certain HTML using PHP's DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, image, curl

I am looking to draw html of a webpage inside my website.

Take this scenario:

I have a website that checks availability of a hotel. But instead of hosting that hotel's images on my server. I simple curl, a specific page on the hotels website that contains their images.

Can I grab anything from the html and display it on my website? using their HTML code, but only the div(s) or images that i want to display?

I'm using this code, sourced from:

http://davidwalsh.name/download-urls-content-php-curl

As practice and arguments sake, lets try and display Google's logo from their homepage.

```
function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('http://www.google.com');
echo '<base href="http://www.google.com/" />';
echo $returned_content;
```

Thanks to @alex I have started to play with DOMDocument in PHP's lib. However, I have hit a snag.

```
    function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$url = "www.abc.net.au";
$html = get_data($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$logo = $dom->getElementById("abcLogo");
var_dump($logo);
```

Returns: `object(DOMElement)[2]`

How do I parse this further? Or Simply just print/echo the contents of the DIV with that id..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have found a DOM element, it can be a bit tricky to get the HTML of the element itself (rather than just its contents).

You can get the XML value of a single element very easily with [`DOMDocument::saveXML`](http://php.net/DOMDocument.saveXML):

```
echo $dom->saveXML($logo);
```

This may be good enough for you.  I believe there is a change coming that will add this functionality to [`saveHTML`](http://php.net/DOMDocument.saveHTML) as well.

Comment: mmmm isn't the question `print/echo the contents of the DIV with that id..?` ? Now if we have to _guess_ the real question...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, run the resulting HTML through something like DOMDocument to extract the portions you require.

Answer (score 1):

`echo $logo->nodeValue` should work because you can only have 1 element by id!